# How to verify if colour of element changed on mouse hovering?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

If mouse is hovered on 'Ask Question' button of https://stackoverflow.com/ website, colour of the button changes to yellow. If I want to make sure, if colour really changes on mouse hover, how can I achieve that using Selenium WebDriver? I couldn't find anything helpful in html dom.

I can hover mouse on element using move_to method but don't know how to check whether colour of button changes? I think, I'll have to check css style but not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `css_value`, see [documentation here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver/Element.html#css_value-instance_method). Note this background color property is on `<li>`, not `<a>` in this particular case.

```
btn_ask_question = driver.find_element(:css, '.nav.askquestion li')
puts btn_ask_question.css_value('background-color')

driver.action.move_to(btn_ask_question).perform
puts btn_ask_question.css_value('background-color')
```

My output (rgba(255, 153, 0, 1) is #FF9900, which is that orange color):

> rgba(119, 119, 119, 1)
>
> rgba(255, 153, 0, 1)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It helped. But move_to hovers mouse but it immediately takes away mouse and hence yellow color doesn't persist till we hit puts btn_ask_question.css_value('background-color'). Hence it returns earlier colour.

Comment: Did you use move_to or something else to persist colour change till we check colour after hovering?